# An alternate sentence to ask somebody to complete their task

Tags: syntactic-analysis

At work, When expecting a document from someone, I email with sentence like these:

> Please provide the document

or

> Can you provide the document?

I think this sentence should not be a question as this person is aware of this task.

Also, I feel this sentence shouldn't start with `please` as it looks like asking a favor.

What's the alternate sentence to use?

Comment: 'Please provide the document.' is a firm but polite request, and is fine. 'Could / Would you please provide the document.' is similar, and possibly even more polite. Note the lack of a question mark, as this is a hedged (polite) request rather than a true question; there is plenty of support for this convention in the literature, and it has been covered on ELU before.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether this person is aware of this task or not. You can just say whatever you want to say, but you need to be more specific, e.g., "Can you send me X document on  Y project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are reading much to much into the word *please* and the fact that it is asked as a question.  That is simply a polite way of communicating a demand in genteel language.  If you were in the military I guess there would be no need for such niceties and the superior would simply bark the order, but in an office environment where everyone tries to get along and where a superior may not want to lord it over his subordinates, using softening language is just a polite idiom everyone understands.

I don't think anyone would interpret using *please* to mean you are asking a favor, in the sense the recipient has a choice of complying or not, especially since the hierarchy is well established (the request coming from a superior to a subordinate).  Every subordinate, at least one who has even a modicum of political smarts, knows that when the boss says, "Please provide the documents...," he/she is not asking a "favor" which can be accepted or ignored.  It is a manner of expression that couches an absolute command in a polite envelope; as polite as it is, it is still a direct order.  No one will mis-interpret that as such.

I have had superiors go even a bit further and use the nicety "Can you please..." when requesting action.  I certainly didn't take that soft lead-in phrase to make the request any less authoritative and emphatic.  It was their way of engendering a sense that we are all in it together.  It soft-peddles the "I'm the boss, you-all are the peons" atmosphere in the office, but be that as it may and yes, it's nice for everyday interaction, the reality is he/she never had to worry that any of us ever forgot who was the boss and who were the peons!

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking time to respond. I like @CinemaDude answer.

Answer (score 1):

> [Please] tell me when I should expect to receive the document.

I think it is better to ask for a **status** update once you have already assigned the task to them than to repeat earlier instruction.

Perhaps this question belongs in https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ ?